# R: For each row, return the k column names of the largest value

Tags: r

I think that example will be more straight forward:

What is the elegant way to achieve the following?

for:

```
DF <- data.frame(V1=c(2,8,1),V2=c(7,3,5),V3=c(9,6,4))
```

and

```
k = 2
```

I would like to get a data frame as following:

1: "V2 V3" # for 7 and 9

2: "V1 V3" # for 8 and 6

3: "V2 V3" # for  5 and 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's elegant enough, but this should work :

```
DF <- data.frame(V1=c(2,8,1),V2=c(7,3,5),V3=c(9,6,4))
k <- 2

mx <- t(apply(DF,1,function(x)names(DF)[sort(head(order(x,decreasing=TRUE),k))]))
> mx
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "V2" "V3"
[2,] "V1" "V3"
[3,] "V2" "V3"
```

Note: `mx` is a matrix, but you can easily get a data.frame using `as.data.frame(mx)`